# SQLite update query for Title Case or Proper Case?

Tags: python, sqlite

I can't quite seem to figure out how to convert a text column of titles into Title Case, or sometimes referred to as Proper Case in SQLite. It doesn't seem to have a propercase() function. I've tried various combinations of upper() and lower() with substr() and text concatenation. But it only changes the first letter in the title and ignores the rest of the words. There must be a method using regex matching in the substr() function? I can use ^(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+$ as the regex matching pattern for the first letter of each word, but is there any other way to do this? My update query is this:

```
update Songs set SongName = UPPER(SUBSTR(SongName, 1, 1)) || SUBSTR(SongName, 2)
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to register a user-defined function (from whatever language you're using to access SQLite).

Comment: @CL, thank you. Any recommendation for how to do that in Python?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function).

Comment: @CL, thanks for the link!